# Javascript: Issues returning a value from a HTML input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a definitive explanation to my ongoing issues with why a function can sometimes output to console log, but won't give a return value.

Specifically in this case, I'm trying to get a value from an HTML input, check whether it passes a test, and return true or false.

I have 4 variations below. What I want is variation 1 to return. It doesn't. It does console log however (which is variation 2.) But to my bewilderment, variation 4, which is the same code as variation 1, but is being called from the console and not a HTML button, does return.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <titleharset="UTF-8">
    <title>Check if number passes a test</title>
</head>
<html>


<body>

  <input type="text" class="input">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="test" onclick="test(document.querySelector('.input').value)">
  <input type="text" class="input2">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="test2" onclick="test2(document.querySelector('.input2').value)">
  <input type="text" class="input3">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="test3" onclick="test3(document.querySelector('.input3').value)">

</body>
<script>
  // Variation 1: Called from HTML input. Doesn't return
  function test(input) {
    if (input % 3 == 0 || input % 7 == 0) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }

  // Variation 2: Called from HTML input. Will console.log
  function test2(input) {
    if (input % 3 == 0 || input % 7 == 0) {
      console.log(true)
    } else {
      console.log(false)
    }
  }

  // Variation 3: Called from HTML input. Set to variable (one return) Doesn't return
  function test3(input) {
    let result = Boolean;
    if (input % 3 == 0 || input % 7 == 0) {
      result = true
    } else {
      result = false
    }
    return result
  }

  // Variation 4: Called from console. Will return!
  function test4(n) {
    if (n % 3 == 0 || n % 7 == 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  console.log(test4(15));
  console.log(test4(21));
  console.log(test4(2));
  console.log(test4(11));
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: its `document.querySelector('.input')[0].value` where `querySelector` return a list

Comment: No, querySelector() returns the first element that matches the selector.

Comment: So you are returning, but you do not use the value... Not sure what you are expecting to happen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are expecting. You are running this code

```
onclick="test(document.querySelector('.input').value)"
```

which calls a function that returns true or false. You do NOTHING with the boolean that is being returned so nothing happens. There is not going to be a log to the console because you are not writing to the console.

So if you are trying to keep the button from submitting, than you would need to add return to the onclick so you can work with it.

```
onclick="return test(document.querySelector('.input').value)"
```

If you want it to write to the console like your 4th example, that is needs to look like the 4th examle in the onclick

```
onclick="console.log(test(document.querySelector('.input').value))"
```

Comment: Thanks! This is answering the crux of my question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is outputting to the console in the second button is your code tells it to

```
function test2(input) {
    if (input % 3 == 0 || input % 7 == 0) {
      console.log(true)
    } else {
      console.log(false)
    }
  }
```

your first and third functions do fire when clicked but they return the values instead of console logging them.

```
function test(input) {
if (input % 3 == 0 || input % 7 == 0) {
  return true
} else {
  return false
}
```

}
I would change the input type to number like so:

```
<input type="number" class="input">
```

that way it is a number but just to be sure I would write all three functions with a Number wrapper making sure the input is a number them console.loggin the results. like so

```
function test2(input) {
var num2 = Number(input);
if (num2 % 3 === 0 || num2 % 7 === 0) {
  console.log(true)
} else {
  console.log(false)
}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

You're trying to do math on a string. Change your `<input>` type attribute from text to number.

Edit: may need to add parseInt() to actually convert to an integer type, not a string type.

Comment: That still returns a string. You'd need to add `parseInt`.